# Ruby Sleep method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I'm working on a geocoding piece/sidekiq job in a Rails/Ruby app.  So basically when we hit the Google API we sleep for 1 second to avoid the Google API query limit.  But I want to push the envelope and speed up processing a bit taking into account AR and SQL time.  So I'm trying to figure out how to sleep for 3/4 of a second.

Can I just do sleep .75 or do I need to do some sort of math on sleep like sleep(1.0 / ??).

Not sure if sleep can take a float like .75 or not.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry, I was away from my computer and posting from my phone.  I should have RTFM first.  Ignore my question.

Answer (score 17):

`sleep 0.75` works pretty good and correct. It accepts float.

> **sleep(*args)** public Suspends the current thread for duration seconds
>   (which may be any number, including a Float with fractional seconds)

http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sleep

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer and pointing me in the right direction, I should have looked at the API docs before asking.  I was mobile and was just thinking out loud.  Appreciate your answer, sorry for the dupe question.